# EF-Code first complex type with a navigational property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

My Model:

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}    

public class User{

    protected User()
    {
        Location = new Location();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }

}
```

When generating the database, I get:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Location' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Locations� is based on type �Location� that has no keys defined.
```

How do I have a navigational property inside a complex type? If I remove the country navigational property, it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Navigation properties (refering to other entities) on a complex type are not supported. You must either make your `Location` an entity (with its own table) or remove the navigation property `Country` from `Location` (and add the `[ComplexType]` attribute as mentioned by Steve Morgan).

**Edit**

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx

> "Complex type cannot contain navigation properties."

Comment: But what about the `CountryID` integer inside `Location` class? Is it possible to make that a foreign key constraint? (I have a similar problem and can't get it to work)

Comment: @Isak: No it is not possible. If you want to have it FK in database you must do it in database directly but EF will not reflect it.

Comment: The fact that this is not supported is mentioned directly in Complex type description on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx

Comment: @Ladislav: Thanks for the reference! I've copied it into the answer.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: ok, thanks. I was half hoping that it would be possible to specify on the parent class (i.e. the actual entity) through the fluent API but I guess not (I couldn't make it work though)

Answer (score 3):

EF wants to infer a primary key for Location, but can't.

Add a `public int LocationId { get; set; }` to the `Location` class and it should be happy.

If you want to use `Location` as a complex type, annotate it with a `[ComplexType]` attribute.

Comment: This will generate a whole new table. I want it as a complex type.