# Navigation Properties for common fields

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5.2

In my model, I have a handful of properties that occur on multiple types. For example, many types have a `CreatedByUserId` and `CreatedDate`. Types that can be updated have a `LastUpdatedByUserId` and `LastUpdatedDate`.

My first thought is to use Complex Types to encapsulate these fields to make my mappings easier. However, as noted below, Complex Types cannot have navigation properties, so no `CreatedByUser` on my entity.

[EF-Code first complex type with a navigational property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603016/ef-code-first-complex-type-with-a-navigational-property)

[EF4 complex type with navigation property (is it possible) or alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266092/ef4-complex-type-with-navigation-property-is-it-possible-or-alternatives)

One option is it use base classes, but now I need 3, CreatedBy only, LastUpdatedBy only, and both. Not to mention this is one of several scenarios, which could lead to a very large number of base classes and that just feels wrong.

Do I just bite the bullet and define these properties on each type? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Here is a method that works for us: http://www.toplinestrategies.com/blogs/entity-framework-set-common-entity-fields-savechanges

Comment: @SteveGreene That looks like a really good pattern. Unfortunately, what I'm trying to do doesn't just apply to tracking fields. I was just using that as a simple example that everyone could understand.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to inherit from
The following will put the properties in BasicBO in the MyClass1s and MyClass2s tables.

> ```
> public class Model1Context : DbContext
> {
>     public Model1Context()
>         : base("name=Model1")
>     {
>         Database.SetInitializer(new Model1Initializer());
>     }
>     public virtual DbSet<MyClass1> MyClass1s { get; set; }
>     public virtual DbSet<MyClass2> MyClass2s { get; set; }
> }
> public class Model1Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Model1Context>
> {
> }
> public class MyClass1 : BasicBO
> {
>     public string MyClass1Stuff { get; set; }
> }
> public class MyClass2 : BasicBO
> {
>     public string MyClass2Stuff { get; set; }
> }
> public class BasicBO
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }  // or whatever
> }
> ```